# Discord.py, как выдать роль при использовании команды?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

```
from SimpleQIWI import *
from time import sleep
import discord

token = "Token"         # https://qiwi.com/api
phone = "number"

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')
        if message.content == 'pay':
            


            api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)

            price = 1              # Минимальное значение при котором счет будет считаться закрытым
            comment = api.bill(price) # Создаем счет. Комментарий с которым должен быть платеж генерируется автоматически, но его можно задать # параметром comment. Валютой по умолчанию считаются рубли, но ее можно изменить параметром currency

            await message.channel.send("Переведите %i рублей на счет %s с комментарием %s" % (price, phone, comment))

            api.start() # Начинаем прием платежей

            while True:
                if api.check(comment): # Проверяем статус
                    await message.channel.send("Платёж получен!")
                    

                       Где то на этом моменте он должен выдать роль по id(человеку который 
                          использовал команду


                    break
    
            time.sleep(1)
            api.stop()


client = MyClient()
  
client.run('Token')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед добавлением возможности выдачи ролей удостоверьтесь в том, что:

1. У бота есть право **"Управлять ролями"**.
2. Роль бота в списке должна находиться выше ролей, которые он может выдавать.

**Код:**

```
async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content == 'pay':

            # здесь ваш код, включительно до  выдачи роли

            while True:
            if api.check(comment): # Проверяем статус
                await message.channel.send("Платёж получен!")

                author = message.author # получаем автора сообщения
                guild = self.get_guild(id) # получаем объект сервера*
                role = guild.get_role(id) # получаем объект роли*

                # как получить id читайте ниже

                await author.add_roles(role) # выдаем автору роль
                await message.channel.send(f"{author.mention}, роль выдана!")
```

Это только на случай, если вы тестируете бота на одном сервере. Если планируете его подключение к нескольким серверам, где id вам могут быть неизвестны, нужно будет сначала программно получать id сервера, затем список всех его ролей и выбирать нужную роль уже из них. Пожалуйста, читайте [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), там есть абсолютно все, что вам нужно знать :)

---

*Чтобы получить id канала, нужно в настройках дискорда, на вкладке "Внешний вид", включить пункт "Режим разработчика". После этого, кликнув правой кнопкой мыши на любой объект, в самом низу у вас будет кнопка "Копировать ID". Так можно получать id пользователей, каналов, серверов и т.п*